# xDebug stopping at context_get

Tags: php, debugging, xdebug

I'm trying to debug my PHP script using `xdebug` and `xdebug_break()` method. It start to working and my IDE (*PHPDesigner*) stop at the break normally, but instantly it stop. Reading the `debug.remote_logs` file I can check that the last line is:

```
<- context_get -i 429 -c 0
```

After that I don't receive a return with a XML data about GET data. So I guess that there live the problem, but how can I fix that?

My php.ini xdebug config is:

```
[xdebug]
  xdebug.remote_mode=jit
  xdebug.remote_enable=1
  xdebug.remote_host=127.0.0.1
  xdebug.remote_port=9000
  xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp
  xdebug.remote_log=C:\Wamp\logs\xdebug.log
  xdebug.idekey=xdebug
```

I tried to use the XDBG too, and it throw an exception and stop to working. The `remote_logs` file show the same fail. Using `php_xdebug-2.2.0-5.4-vc9.dll`.

Answer (score 0):

Before I do post it, I checked out the xDebug last version and it is `php_xdebug-2.2.2-5.4-vc9.dll` (diff: old 2.2.0, new 2.2.2). Updating that solve my problem and now all works fine. Yey!